# Xcode cannot run iOS simulator

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

Version 8.0 beta 5.

I've recently installed the above beta version of Xcode but I'm unable to run any iOS 10.0 simulators.  I've done various uninstalls on both the 8 beta and Xcode 7, clearing out directories and reboots but no success.  After reinstalling I still can't run iOS 10.0 simulators.  (I've copied the Xcode download to another machine and successfully unpacked and installed it there without any problems, so it's not a corrupt download.)

xcrun yields the following information...
09:44:13 ~ > xcrun simctl list
`== Device Types ==
iPhone 4s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s)
iPhone 5 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5)
iPhone 5s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5s)
:
iPad Pro (9.7-inch) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro--9-7-inch-)
iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro)
Apple TV 1080p (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-TV-1080p)
== Runtimes ==
iOS 8.1 (8.1 - 12B411) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-8-1)
iOS 9.3 (9.3 - 13E233) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-3)
iOS 10.0 (10.0 - 14A5335a) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-10-0) (unavailable, failed to open liblaunch_sim.dylib)
tvOS 10.0 (10.0 - 14T5321a) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.tvOS-10-0)
== Devices ==
-- iOS 8.1 --
-- iOS 9.3 --
-- iOS 10.0 --
-- tvOS 10.0 --
== Device Pairs ==
09:44:18 ~ >`

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is Xcode returning you any kind of error message?

Comment: Opening a new playground results in the error message "Failed to launch process.  The iOS 10.0 simulator runtime is not available."

When running unit tests on an app (on an iPhone 6s Plus simulator) then the simulator app throws up a pop-up with the message "Unable to determine device." followed by another with the message "Unable to boot device in current state: Creating".

Comment: /Library/Developer/Coresimulator/Profiles/Runtimes contains subdirectories 'iOS 8.1.simruntime' and 'iOS 9.3.simruntime' only.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

```
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
```

This brought my simulators back to the run menu, allowed me to add more, and my simulators actually now run again. (Xcode 10b6).

Strangely enough, seemed to clear up a system header build problem too.. now my extra system header search directory location works and no compile error indicating it can't find the files and I did not mod the project.

Comment: The bug is still present in 10.3

Comment: working for me, thanks.
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-5 simulator runtime is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working.  I (for the third or fourth time) deleted `Xcode-beta.app` and `Xcode.app` and also all the associated files and directories I could find (using the free app `AppDelete Lite.app`.  In addition, I also deleted the `/Application/Contents/` directory.

Then, I extracted the `Xcode-beta.app` again and installed it as normal and it all worked.  I'd be happier if I could pin down the cause of the problem and happier still if I could get the lost two days of my life back but at least everything appears to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:
`killall "Simulator" 2> /dev/null; xcrun simctl erase all`

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I do appreciate it but I posted this problem three years ago and have moved on since then.  I am now running Xcode 11β3 (without any problems, so far).